# Populating $form_input with 'select' element options?

Tags: perl, html-formfu

I'm trying to understand the data-structure required to populate a
form with 'select' element values (options).

When I dump (Data::Dumper) the FormFu object, I see that the object structure
looks similar to the following:

```
'name' => 'EmailDL',
'_options' => [
         {
           'label_attributes' => {},
           'value' => 'm',
           'container_attributes' => {},
           'label' => 'Male',
           'attributes' => {}
         },
         {
           'label_attributes' => {},
           'value' => 'f',
           'container_attributes' => {},
           'label' => 'Female',
           'attributes' => {}
         }
       ],
```

Seeing this, I figured that the way to structure $form_input (being that `$form_input = \%cgivars`) would be something like the following:

```
     'Firstname' => 'Faisal',
     'EmailDL' => [
                    {
                      'value' => 'myvalue',
                      'label' => 'mylabel'
                    }
                  ],
```

However this doesn't seem to work.  I've found that structuring `$form_input` correctly, and then issuing a `$fu->default_values($form_input)` to be simple and effective, except in this instance when I'm trying to include the select/options sub-structure.

So the question is:  How should I structure 'EmailDL' above to correctly populate 'select' options when doing `$fu->default_values($form_input)` or `$fu->process($form_input)`?

Answer (score 1):

To set the options you use the options call,

```
$fu->get_all_element('EmailDL')->options([ [ 'myvalue', 'mylabel' ], 
                                             [ 'val2', 'label2' ] ]);
```

If you then want to set one of those values you can use the default_values.

```
$fu->default_values({ EmailDL => 'val2' });
```

Further help is available here in the [Element::Group](http://search.cpan.org/~perler/HTML-FormFu-0.09005/lib/HTML/FormFu/Role/Element/Group.pm#options) documentation.  Note the code examples are in the text of the help.